# How to properly define shim config with requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have `jQuery` and a `jQuery` plugin loaded via `RequireJS`.

This is how my `requirejs.config` looks like:

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: "http://mysite.example.com",
"paths": {

    // libraries
    "jquery": "Static/js/library/jquery/jquery-1.10.2",
    "jquery_sortable" : "Static/js/library/jquery-sortable/jquery-sortable",

    shim: {
        'jquery_sortable': ['jquery']
    }
}
});
```

When I refresh the page two times or more very quickly, `sometimes` I get an exception in the plugin code that:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`.

Basically, my plugin does not use the `shim` I have set for it.

What is the most reliable way to specify my `shim` config ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's weird because all the examples I have seen online put the `shim` config at the last bit of the `requirejs.config` but putting it at the top seemed to solve MY problem.

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "http://mysite.example.com",
    shim: {
            'jquery_sortable': ['jquery']
        },
    "paths": {

        // libraries
        "jquery": "Static/js/library/jquery/jquery-1.10.2",
        "jquery_sortable" : "Static/js/library/jquery-sortable/jquery-sortable"

    }
});
```

Comment: ilpaijin has the answer. You originally put your ``shim`` inside ``paths``, which is incorrect. Your fix works because as you moved ``shim`` before ``paths`` you *also* moved it outside ``paths``. If you move ``shim`` after ``paths`` but keep it outside ``paths``, your config is going to work just as well.

Comment: Like I commented above,: no, it must have been an error when I was trying to paste my code into `stackoverflow`. I am certainly sure this is not the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Could be because you were not constructing as expected. As you notice you were putting `shim` inside `paths`. May be.

```
"paths": {

// libraries
"jquery": "Static/js/library/jquery/jquery-1.10.2",
"jquery_sortable" : "Static/js/library/jquery-sortable/jquery-sortable",

shim: {
    'jquery_sortable': ['jquery']
}
```

}

-------EDIT AFTER COMMENT------

Maybe trying to define the dep as declared in the manual?

```
'foo': {
    deps: ['bar'],
    ...
```

source: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Comment: No, it must have been an error when I was trying to paste my code into `stackoverflow`. I am certainly sure this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that this occurs because RequireJS is loading scripts asynchronously. This happens for performance reasons, i.e. scripts will be loaded in parallel. This is OK for normal AMD modules; RequireJS will keep the dependency tree from the `define(["deps"], function(){...})` calls but will *defer* the execution of `function()` until its dependencies are resolved.

However with non-AMD, shimmed modules (like jQuery-UI), the entire script will be executed on load. This means that, if by any chance the "sortable" is loaded before "jquery", it will *not* find its dependency and fail as you write.

I believe the only robust workaround is to include jQuery as a plain old `<script>` tag, right after `require.js`. This way you cannot use the `data-main` attribute to load your entry point, you will have to `require` it separately:

```
<script src="scripts/lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    require(["app/bootstrap"]);
</script>
```